# TypeError: Type error when working with typed arrays

Tags: c#, javascript, typed-arrays

When I trying to convert my XHR response to `TypedArray` in JavaScript, I get:

> TypeError: Type error

This is my server-side code (ASP.NET Web Form):

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int number = 4;
        Response.BinaryWrite(BitConverter.GetBytes(number));
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

And Here my client-side code:

```
xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:6551/Default.aspx", false);  
xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=x-user-defined");  
xhr.send(null);
var sss = new DataView(xhr.response);
```

Also when I try to convert the `xhr.response` with `Int16Array` I get this error:

> RangeError: Size is too large (or is negative).

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: What's inside your "`xhr.response`" ?

Comment: @MarcoK Should I tell you the response (using Firebug etc.)?

Comment: Yup, that's what I meant (`console.log(xhr.response)` and place the results)

Comment: @MarcoK Oops! When I `console.log` that, I can't see anything. That's seems empty but I really did `Response.BinaryWrite` (see my server-side code).

Answer (score 2):

Ok I find out the problem, I should use `xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";` in the XHR request and the code finally is:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:6551/Default.aspx", true);
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer"; 
xhr.onload = function(e) {
  var arraybuffer = xhr.response; // not responseText
  console.log(new Uint32Array(arraybuffer));
}
xhr.send();
```

More detail: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Thanks for your help @MarcoK.

Comment: No problem, glad you found the solution!